# get milliseconds since 1970 from string

Tags: ruby

I got a string like this:

```
"2016-08-12 06:13:24 UTC"
```

How can I convert this date time string to **milliseconds** since January 1, 1970 UTC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse("2016-08-12 06:13:24 UTC").strftime('%Q')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my answer. `%s` is for seconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.

Comment: It's also possible here to use `DateTime.parse(...).to_i` I believe.

Comment: I tried on Ruby 2.3.1 but no `undefined method to_i for #<DateTime:0x007fa69d01a8d8>`

Comment: Ah maybe, it doesn't apply to `DateTime`, I used `Time.utc(2016, 8, 12, 6, 13, 24).to_i`, and also `require 'time'`

Comment: You know, I think the method you are talking about is a Rails method but it gets seconds, not milliseconds. `to_i: Converts self to an integer number of seconds since the Unix epoch.`

Comment: Same for time, number of seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Looks like you're right, in addition to this it's used for getting elapsed from `Unix Epoch`, my bad

Comment: @px06 You were close. :) You can do `DateTime.parse("2016-08-12 06:13:24 UTC").to_time.to_f` and multiply the result by 1,000 to get milliseconds.